# why javac suppress Sun proprietary API warnings if bootclasspath option specified

Tags: java, javac, lint

I am trying to enable the sunapi lint but found it impossible with conjunction of `bootclasspath` using

A simple java file: `test.java`

```java
class Untitled {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sun.misc.BASE64Encoder shouldWarned;
    }
}
```

It would be reported while compiling by default

```sh
javac test.java -Werror -J-Duser.language=en
```

```
test.java:3: warning: BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
        sun.misc.BASE64Encoder shouldWarned;
                ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
1 warning
```

but if we add `bootclasspath` option

```
javac test.java -Werror -J-Duser.language=en -bootclasspath $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

Nothing reported, all compiled normally

What's wrong with javac? How could I enable the sunapi warning both with `bootclasspath` using